# How do I directly access a memory mapped register of AVR with C

Tags: c

Assume I want to write the following without using `DDRD` or `PORTD`:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    PORTD = 0xFF; 
}
```

I found this link which includes a list of mapped registers to memory addresses:
https://github.com/DarkSector/AVR/blob/master/asm/include/m328Pdef.inc

So I replaced one of the keywords with a pointer:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    unsigned char *portd = 0x0b;
    *portd = 0xFF;
}
```

But it's not working (my LED isn't turning on with the second code). Why is that?

Comment: It might get optimized out, as it's not volatile. Or it's using wrong instruction to store data so it needs different address.

Comment: 1. If you'd use `unsigned char *portd = &PORTD;` would your pointer work for port manipulation? That would lead to #2. 2. From [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/reach-io-port-directly-pointer):
`unsigned char * myportA = (unsigned char *) 0x003B;` Of course, adjusted to your microcontroller. If that works for you, I lack of knowledge why would you need to cast it, but if passing the port name by reference works (#1) and direct assign using the hex doesn't, it has something to do with that. 3. Could declaring the pointer variable volatile help, in case something else modifies it?

Comment: what in this question is about Arduino?

Answer (score 11):

It's worth exploring how `PORTD` is defined in the actual AVR header file.  The relevant file is `iom328p.h`, and it's defined as:

```
#define PORTD   _SFR_IO8(0x0B)
```

`_SFR_IO8` is defined as

```
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
```

and

```
#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
```

This shows that 0x0b is *not* the address of the `PORTD` register, but its offset from the address `__SFR_OFFSET`, which is 0x20.  Indeed, if you look at the ATMEGA328 datasheet, the register summary shows that `PORTD` is at offset 0x2b.  So that is the address that you would want to access via a pointer.

Note that this also shows the type of the pointer, if we fully expand the original definition of `PORTD` we get:

```
#define PORTD   _SFR_IO8(0x0B)
#define PORTD _MMIO_BYTE((0x0B) + __SFR_OFFSET)
#define PORTD _MMIO_BYTE((0x0B) + 0x20)
#define PORTD (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x2B))
```

This syntax takes the integer 0x2B, casts it to type `pointer to volatile uint8_t`, and dereferences that pointer so you can assign to or read from the location the pointer references.  The `volatile` qualifier is important because it prevents the compiler from optimizing out accesses to memory.  Without it, the compiler may store the value to a register instead, or not store it at all, which would mean your IO port would remain unchanged or appear to report an incorrect value.

To go back to the title of your question, you have asked how to "directly access a memory mapped register in C", well the answer is you do that exactly the way the header file defines for you:

```
(*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x2B) = 0xFF
```

aka

```
PORTD = 0xff
```

There is no more direct way than this.  The compiler sees a literal address and writes to it.  What you've written is very different (adjusting to use the correct address and type:

```
volatile uint8_t * portd = 0x2b;
 *portd = 0xFF;
```

This allocates a location in memory symbolized by `portd`, which holds the value 0x2B.  When you write `*portd = foo`, the MCU has to access the location where `portd` is stored, take the value found there as an address to find the location you actually want to write to.  This method requires that you allocate a place in memory to hold `portd` and requires an extra memory access to be able to read or write to the port register.  This method is therefore *indirect*.

In reality, if optimization is enabled, the compiler may optimize the pointer away and replace it with the same literal access as in the PORTD case, however this depends on the program structure, and in particular the qualification and scope of the pointer.  Limiting the scope of `portd` as much as possible and/or declaring it as `volatile uint8_t * const portd = 0x2b` (which indicates that the pointer's value is constant even if the value *pointed to* is volatile) will increase the likelihood of the pointer being optimized away.

---

The reason the AVR headers define the IO port registers this way is because in addition to the standard load/store instructions that can access the entire data memory address space and take three clock cycles to complete, the IO registers are special, and can also be accessed using IN/OUT instructions, which complete in two cycles.  The load/store instructions use the memory address for the IO registers (starting at offset 0x20), whereas the IN/OUT instructions use the IO address, which starts at 0x00, but corresponds to 0x20 in the memory address space.  From the datasheet:
[image]

So when you access an IO location, the optimizer should recognize that it can issue a more efficient instruction than the standard load/store, and it will replace the load/store to 0x2b with an in/out to 0x0b.

Comment: Re “ This method requires that you allocate a place in memory to hold `portd` and requires an extra memory access”: Not really. It compiles to the exact same machine code as `PORTD = 0xff`.

Comment: It may get *optimized* to the same instructions, but the abstract C machine is instructed to do as I described and there is no guarantee that such optimization will take place.  It will depend on the scope of `portd` and optimization level, but in any case it's still not *more* direct than using the existing `PORTD` macro.

Comment: You may then want to make it clearer in your answer that by “the MCU” you mean the abstract C machine, not the actual MCU.

Comment: The behavior of the target must be equivalent to the behavior of the abstract machine; that's the whole point.  Accessing a literal address is only equivalent to accessing a dereferenced pointer in a limited subset of cases, therefore the compiler will issue instructions for pointer dereferencing *unless it can determine that the literal access is equivalent*.  Try different scopes and qualifications for `portd` and see what instructions are emitted.  In any case, it's worth mentioning the optimization, so I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Re “Try different scopes and qualifications for `portd`”: for the specific case of the question, it _will_ be optimized away. There is no “may”. If you manage to coerce the compiler to store the pointer, I would love to see it, but it will will clearly be a _very different_ code from the one in the question.

Comment: See: I have seen many beginners here who are prone to misguided micro-optimization attempts. Some are confused because they severely _underestimate_ the compiler's ability to optimize. Never the contrary. Some avoid using variables for intermediate results under the misconception that they are reducing RAM consumption. Truth is they are only reducing program readability. Your explanations about the purported cost of the `portd` variable can only reinforce this misconception. Using intermediate variables is one of those cases where one should _really_ trust the compiler to micro-optimize.

Comment: You're right, it is almost always best to let the compiler worry about optimizations like this. However, it *is* important to understand that in the two different cases you are telling the machine to do two different things, even if the syntax looks quite similar.  It's also important to understand how scope and qualification affects compiler behavior.  FWIW, when `portd` has global scope and is non-const, I still get pointer instructions at any optimization level with AVR-GCC 4.9.2.  

Further discussion on this tangent should probably happen in chat.